# how to validate that Kafka consumer received a message

Tags: java, spring-boot, apache-kafka

I have a scenario on my application, where I am making a REST request to an endpoint and I only want the response to be sent back when a kafka consumer received a message from a producer. I have a listener on the consumer but I am not sure how link between the listener and the API execution, so that it stops it until the consumer receives a message. any ideas? Thanks

EDIT This is the example I am trying to work on

This is the consumer listener

```
 @Component
    public class ReplyingKafkaConsumer {

        @KafkaListener(topics = "${kafka.topic.request-topic}")
        @SendTo
        public UserRequest listen(UserRequest request) throws InterruptedException {

            UserRequest response = new UserRequest();
            response.setCompanyId(68L);
            response.setCompanyName("AdiBas");
            response.setEmail("adibas@gmail.com");
            response.setUserId(102L);

            return response;
        }
```

and  I need to listen on the consumer from within this REST API

```
 @ResponseBody
    @PostMapping(value = "/user", produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE, consumes = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
    public UserRequest post(@RequestBody UserRequest request) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException {
        // create producer record
        ProducerRecord<String, UserRequest> record = new ProducerRecord<>(requestTopic, request);
        // set reply topic in header
        record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, requestReplyTopic.getBytes()));
        // post in kafka topic
        RequestReplyFuture<String, UserRequest, UserRequest> sendAndReceive = kafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);

        // confirm if producer produced successfully
        SendResult<String, UserRequest> sendResult = sendAndReceive.getSendFuture().get();

        //print all headers
        sendResult.getProducerRecord().headers().forEach(header -> System.out.println(header.key() + ":" + header.value().toString()));

        // get consumer record
        ConsumerRecord<String, UserRequest> consumerRecord = sendAndReceive.get();
        // return consumer value
        return consumerRecord.value();
    }
```

Comment: Did you try something by yourself that you could show us?

Comment: I edited the question with some sample code. Thanks

Comment: Do you want the producer to send a message too as part of this API?

Comment: yes I want the message consumed to be sent as a part of the API response

Comment: I think you're misunderstanding asynchronous flows. You could make the consumer forward data to a websocket to update the web client. It shouldn't be part of the blocking http request response flow. In other words, the kafka listener is always running and it's bad practice to block it, or pause it to wait for events